# Input::file('filename') returning null Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Here is my code in view:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'add_auto', 'class'=>'form-horizontal', 'files'=>true, 'method'=>'GET']) !!}
   {!! Form::file('file1'); !!}
   {!! Form::submit('Click Me!'); !!}
{!! Form::close()!!}
```

And in controller:

```
if ($request->hasFile('file1')) {
   $file1 = $request->file('file1');
   $request->file('file1')->move('../public/img');
}else{
        echo 'Has not any file!';
}
```

I can not retrieve and save in directory this file, because it says there is no file and returns null. But if we write in controller:

```
dd($request->all());
```

Then it shows:

```
array:1 [▼
"file1" => "list.txt"
]
```

Where is the problem?!!

Comment: Out of curiosity, would you be able to run this as a `$_POST` request instead of a `$_GET` see if you get a different result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FORM` element with submission type `GET` cannot transfer files! It has to be `POST`, plus, you have to set the `enctype` property to `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Using `'files'=>true` at array parameters does the trick for `multipart/form-data`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call the method "file" two times.
In your controller, simply type this :

```
if ($request->hasFile('file1')) {
    $file1 = $request->file('file1');
    $file1->move('../public/img');
} else {
    echo 'Has not any file!';
}
```